# React page keep footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem when try to fix footer at bottom of the page as below picture:

[image]

Although I google and see many suggestions, but I'm still facing the problem. I suspect this problem is `<div data-reactroot></div>` cannot be set height 100% as its parents. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**:
Style of footer:

```
borderTop: '1px solid #ddd',
height: '60px',
lineHeight: '60px',
backgroundColor: 'white'
```

Comment: Make sure you set your `html, body { height: 100% }`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure `html, body { height: 100% }`

Comment: I tried to set `height` and/or `min-height` of `<div id="bms-root">` is 100% but I get same result.

Comment: What is the current footer problem? What would a fixed footer look like?

Comment: I want to fix footer at bottom of page. That means footer should always be shown at bottom.

Comment: Can you show us the styles of the footer, too?

Comment: @mwoelk I've updated the question to show style of footer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to tell your footer to position itself to the bottom of the surrounding container:

Footer css:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

And for the container (the react-root div):

```
padding-bottom:60px;
```

---

As an alternative (if you don't need to support IE 8) you could try this style on the `div.container` :

```
height: calc(100% - 60px);
```

Comment: That works correctly. Thank you again. Btw how can i make text 'No Result' at the center of screen?

Comment: This solution isn't scroll friendly, When scrolled the footer is stuck to its initial position

Comment: If you need a scroll friendly solution use position:fixed; to always keep it at the bottom. You may also need to add a z-index to keep it above other elements.

Answer (score 12):

For any other person the above solutions do not work for, you could try the following steps:

1. Give the **parent** `div` a non-static `position` such as `relative` (remember the default `position` is `static`)
2. Give the **parent** div a minimum height of `100vh`; this enables it to take up all available space vertically
3. Then for the footer (**child**), which should be wrapped in a `div` if not one, give it the following properties; `position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%`.

**UPDATE**: In some cases, setting the footer `div` `position` to `absolute` may not work. In such a case, use `relative` instead.

Hopefully, the steps above should fix it :-)

Comment: It seems that "relative" only works on pages longer than the browser window and "absolute" only works on pages with smaller or equal height as the browser window.

Comment: Yeah @Lerk, it seems so

Answer (score 8):

One trick I believe everyone is missing here is that in React after html and body element, there is also a div with **#root** which encloses the entire content. Please refer to the image below.

[image]

So, it is required to make the height 100% of all 3 i.e. html, body and #root.

```
html, body, #root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then add these properties in #root:

```
#root {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

You must wonder that why this the #root needs to be flex and not the body. The reason is that it is the innermost parent or I should say the closest parent of the footer.

Now, finally just do this for the footer:

```
footer: { margin-top: auto }
```

What the above line does is it pushes the footer at the end of its parent.
As simple as that. Nothing fancy here. No need to do any calc on height or change the position of footer.

Answer (score 6):

It is important to have content wrapper and set its min-height to 100vh:

```
min-height: 100vh; (100% of the viewport height)

min-height: 100%; (100% of the parent's element height)
```

Look at here is very well explained and worked for me:
https://medium.com/@zerox/keep-that-damn-footer-at-the-bottom-c7a921cb9551

Answer (score 6):

I would change the footer css as follows:

```
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
```

It is possible to have a `position: absolute` but it won't be scrolling-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

### flex-grow

Quite late to the party but my solution was:

```html
<div className="layout">
  <Navbar />
    <main>
      {children}
    </main>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

```css
.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.layout main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to have a wrapper for your page so you can absolutely position the footer at the bottom? If so, you can create a new component with relative position for that and pass the others in as children and give your footer absolute positioning at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Wish I read it earlier.
Here is the snippet for [Ikechuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4100025/ikechukwu-kalu) answer and note that now the `footer` also respect the margin (which may not in any other answers above):

```css
html, body, div{
      height:100%;
      width:100%
      display:block;
    }
    footer{
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      display:block;  
      width:100%
      
 }
 hr{
      display: block;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
    margin-block-start: 0.5em;
    margin-block-end: 0.5em;
    margin-inline-start: auto;
    margin-inline-end: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div style={"margin=5%;"}>
<div style={"position:relative"}>
<footer>
  <hr>
  I am footer
</footer>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @mwoelk had the question answered. I just would like to make it clearer for the beginner.

Step 1 --- Footer css:

```css
.Footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Step 2 --- Wraper of Footer css: (Let's use React as an example, usually footer is wrapped inside .App. The reason for adding padding bottom is to avoid some part of the content is covered by Footer at the bottom if content is too long.)

```css
.App {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS class for the Footer

```
.c-mt-auto {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

and this for the container `<div>` that contains the body and the Footer

```
.c-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex

```
html, body, #root {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
#root {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
header, footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

1. you need first wrap your App component in container:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div className="container" >
    <App />
    </div>
  </Provider>
);
```

with ccs styles:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

2. second step add to your footer
    `margin-top: auto;`